# How can fix the error :" '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int' "?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I want to construct the matrices `S`, `I`, `H`, `L`, and `DS0`. I have been able to create everything but `DS0`. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy.matrices import  zeros
from gekko import GEKKO    
n=3;z=1`

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = [sp.symbols('x%d' % i) for i in range(8*n-4)]

t=sp.symbols('t ')

B=np.zeros((n,n))
number = range(n)
for i in number:
   for j in number:
       if i<j :
           B[i][j]=0
       else :
           B[i][j]=sp.factorial(i+j)/(2**j*sp.factorial(j)*sp.factorial(i-j))
PS=[x[0:n]];PI=[x[n:2*n]];PH=[x[2*n:3*n]];PL=[x[3*n:4*n]]
TS=[[1]];TI=[[1]];TH=[[1]];TL=[[1]]
for i in range(n-1):
    TS.append([t**(x[4*n+i]+i+1)])   
    TI.append([t**(x[5*n+i-1]+i+1)])
    TH.append([t**(x[6*n+i-2]+i+1)])
    TL.append([t**(x[7*n+i-3]+i+1)])
S=np.dot(np.dot(PS,B),TS)
I=np.dot(np.dot(PI,B),TI)
H=np.dot(np.dot(PH,B),TH)
L=np.dot(np.dot(PL,B),TL)
DS0=zeros((n,n))
for i in number:
    if i==0:
       DS0[i][i]=0
   
    else:
     DS0[i][i]=sp.gamma(x_4*n+i+1)/sp.gamma(x_4*n+i+1-z)

print (DS0)
```

After running this code, I get the error: `'<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'`.

### edit

```
line 1212, in zeros if rows < 0 or cols < 0: 
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur? Please provide the full error message. There are also some syntax errors in your current code. For example, `x_4` is undefined. And if Gekko is irrelevant to this question then you should remove those lines from the example. It's best to strip the examples down to just what is important for the question because extra things distract from the actual problem.

Comment: 1.) Please format your code according to PEP 8. 2.) Please reduce the code to make it a [mre]. Focus on minimal. My guess is that this problem can be reproduced with half the code. 3.) Learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The minimum code would be `from sympy.matrices import zeros`,
`n = 3`,`DS0 = zeros((n, n))`. Do you see the problem?

Comment: I think making `B` a list of list instead of sympy zeros would be better

Comment: `np.zeros` takes a tuple of dimensions.  `sympy.zeros` takes separate numbers, `sympy.zeros(n,n)`.  Again, I caution against mixing numpy and sympy.  And make sure you read the right documentation.  Don't assume functions for one work exactly the same was as for the other.  Even as a experienced programmer I like to have an interactive session at hand where I can test pieces of code.  With the right imports I can confirm that `sympy.zeros((3,3))` produces this error, while `np.zeros((3,3))` does not.

Comment: the traceback tells us that the error is in `DS0=zeros((n,n))`, and has something to do with checking the `rows` or `cols` value.  From the docs I see it's supposed to be `zeros(rows, cols)`.  `sympy` (and numpy) runs in python, so learning to read and debug **basic python** is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are calling the `zeros` function that you define with `from sympy.matrices import zeros` and not the intended `np.zeros` on the line where you define `DS0 = zeros((n,n))`. Just replace this with `DS0 = np.zeros((n,n))`
Then it's running (appart from the issue of `x_4` not being defined, as pointed out by @jared in a comment, but this will likely not be a problem in your own code)

Comment: OP is not calling a builtin `zeros` function, but the one from `sympy.matrices`...

Comment: I mean x_{4*n+i}; in other word the expression 4*n+i is index. If i use DS0=np.zeros((n,n)) the error"Cannot convert expression to floating python" will occure

Comment: Never mind... Now that you have edited it, I shall delete my comments.

Comment: he was told in the previous question to stop using sympy and numpy together.  He's still using `np.dot`

Comment: Thanks for your all answers. my mistake was using sympy and numpy together